# Нужна ли запятая после «так»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, наречия

> Всего было собрано 17 табличек, но Сыма Цо добыл две, оставив лишнюю
> себе, и одной из команд не хватило таблички, поэтому все её участники
> не были допущены к регистрации.
> Так(,) из 206 человек 15 не смогли получить допуск.

Answer (score 3):

Слово [ТАК](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Tak-71262.html) многозначно, оно может быть наречием, частицей, союзом, вводным словом.
Думаю, что в нашем контексте по смыслу "так" является местоименным наречием со значением *именно таким образом* (каким? — рассказывается в предыдущем предложении). В этом случае запятая после "так" не нужна.
***Так** из 206 человек 15 не смогли получить допуск.*
(Ударение делается на "так", паузы нет.)

Так из семени рождается дерево, из оплодотворенной яйцеклетки ― человек. [Александр Грудинкин. Топливо, таблетки, Марс // «Знание - сила», 2011]

Теоретически возможен и вариант с вводным словом (значение: например, к примеру сказать. *Климат там суровый: так, морозы доходят до сорока градусов. Слишком много читает: так, вчера прочитала целую книгу*), но мне он кажется менее вероятным.